# How to find the locations on map using web services?

Tags: android, web-services, location

I am new to android development. I am developing an app where user has to record location and later locate the car where he has parked.I am not sure how to use web services here.How do I use web services here to find the car parked on map? Also I have given the values of latitude and longitude manually.What should be done?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your need web service to communicate with web service to send and get data.Try this link it help you.

Check the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)

Thanks.

Comment: user records the location and it gets saved in file explorer as .txt file.then user clicks locate car and parked car has to be shown on map